# NHibernate disables insert batching at the ADO level transparently if I use an identiy identifier generator. Why?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, batch-processing

Related to [this document](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch) :

NHibernate disables insert batching at the ADO level transparently if I use an identiy identifier generator.  Why?

If I use identity for generating identifier, How can I use batch processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identity needs a round trip to the database, so you can know which id was generated. More details here :

- http://ayende.com/blog/3915/nhibernate-avoid-identity-generator-when-possible
- http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.aspx
- http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/02/nh210-generators-behavior-explained.html

Comment: Exactly. It can't be done. http://ayende.com/blog/3915/nhibernate-avoid-identity-generator-when-possible